# Ack messages on receipt with Spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration, spring-amqp

I have a use case where I'd like to ack the message as soon as the application receives it rather than waiting for the flow to complete. Flow is below. Currently the simple message listener container is configured with AUTO acknowledgement mode.

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow processAggregateEventFlow(SimpleMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer,
                                                         @Qualifier("errorChannel") MessageChannel eventErrorChannel) {
    
            return IntegrationFlows
                    // Create message listener container and queueEvent error channel
                    .from(Amqp.inboundAdapter(messageListenerContainer).errorChannel(eventErrorChannel))
                    .transform(new JsonToObjectTransformer(Request.class, jacksonConfiguration.jsonObjectMapper()))
                    .filter(Request.class, e -> true)
                    .handle(requestMessageHandler)
                    .get();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

See `AcknowledgeMode.NONE` and read their JavaDocs:

```
public enum AcknowledgeMode {

    /**
     * No acks - {@code autoAck=true} in {@code Channel.basicConsume()}.
     */
    NONE,

    /**
     * Manual acks - user must ack/nack via a channel aware listener.
     */
    MANUAL,

    /**
     * Auto - the container will issue the ack/nack based on whether
     * the listener returns normally, or throws an exception.
     * <p><em>Do not confuse with RabbitMQ {@code autoAck} which is
     * represented by {@link #NONE} here</em>.
     */
    AUTO;
```

With the `MANUAL` there are a couple headers added to the message from that AMQP Inbound Channel Adapter:

```
            headers.put(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG, deliveryTag);
            headers.put(AmqpHeaders.CHANNEL, channel);
```

So you can have a `.handle()` just after that `from(Amqp)` to call  `channel.basicAck(deliveryTag, false);`. See more in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/amqp.html#amqp-inbound-ack